# jsPDF text between two elements

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

I am trying to insert a text between two elements in pdf via javascript. I know the coordinates of both elements and I want text to be in the middle of this two coordinates.

I have tried to find width of text and find starting point of text. However, there is not useful function to find width of text.

Answer (score 0):

I solves it.
I just find width of text by using pdf.getTextWidth(text) and divided by 2. Then make a minus from y middle.